# How to maintain the order of key added in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I didn't knew this at first place, I thought that the key/value pair I am adding to my dictionary will be in the same order when I try to retrieve it back...

Now here is my question -

I have a ViewController which I have made as singleton, inside this VC I have defined:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;
```

Now I try accessing this dictionary from various other classes and set its contents via:

```
[[[ViewController sharedViewController] dictionary] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBOOL:NO] forKey:@"xx"] , yy ,zz and so on
```

I have my delegates implemented which would hit for a particular key(xx,yy,zz and so on). Now whenever a particular delegate method is hit I need to update my dictionary with same key but `[NSNumber numberWithBOOL:YES]` which is happening .. but the order in which I added the items in dictionary is not maintained ... How can I achieve this?? I need to maintain the order in the same way in which I have added my items to the dictionary at first place??

Can someone please help me out??

Comment: Read the documentation.  An NSDictionary is unordered.

Comment: Besides that, your description makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed, you should use `NSArray` to have your values ordered. You can also use some 3rd party APIs like: [M13OrderedDictionary](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13OrderedDictionary) or others, however, that's not a pretty solution.

Obviously, the desired solution is to create your own object or struct and keep an array of those objects/structs.

Answer (score 1):

`NSDictionary` is just a mapping between keys and values that has no defined order. If you try to iterate over the keys, you may or may not get them back in the same order you added them, and you should never depend on the ordering of the keys when iterating over them.

One thing you could do is create an `NSArray` that contains the keys in the order you want them. Then you can iterate over the keys in the array and get the values from the `NSDictionary` in the order you wanted. The combination of these two basically gives you a sorted key `NSDictionary`.

Another thing you could do is to just use an `NSArray` to stores the values, unless the keys that you're using matter as well. But if all you're trying to do is get the values in a certain order, then I would say `NSArray` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of key by using the following code:

```
NSArray *allKeys = [dictionary allKeys];
```

Then, the keys all saved in order and you can access particular value by getting specific key in allKeys array and retrieving it by using `dictionary[allKeys[2]]`.

Comment: How does that preserve the order in which the values were added?

Comment: When new value is added, you should add the key to array at the same time.

Comment: The documentation for `-[NSDictionary allKeys]` explicitly states: "The order of the elements in the array is not defined.", so you should never expect the array returned by `allKeys` to be in the same order you added them in.

Comment: Then maybe you can define a new data type including a dictionary and a mutable ordered set. Define a custom function to add a key and value to dictionary and add the key to ordered set at the same time.

Comment: That is the standard way, yes.  Use the array for the table view data source and when displaying, use its value as the key into the dictionary.  There are many questions about this here.